# Is there an approximate correction for bias in correlating probability distribution estimates?

Tags: correlation, bias, density-estimation

I'm computing the correlation between two probability distributions $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ that I am measuring empirically. Call the estimates $S(x)$ and $T(x)$. The data is binned, so the estimates of the distributions are effectively draws from a multinomial distribution. I can then compute the correlation between the estimates $S(x)$ and $T(x)$, but this estimate is biased towards zero by the estimation error.

I've found a correction factor for correlations when the parameters are independent and Gaussianly distributed, but that is not the case here. Is there another correction factor that is useful in this case?

**Major edit for clarity**: The distributions $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ don't have any known structure but they are discrete distributions. After getting $N_P$ samples from $P$ I can create an estimate of $P$ by counting the number of occurrences in each bin of $P$ and dividing by $N_P$. For example, if x is from 1 to 10 and $N_P = 100$, if I get 10 draws where $x=1$ then my estimate is $S(x=1)=10/100=0.1$

So after repeating the same procedure for $Q$ I have $S$ and $T$. Since both of these distributions are discrete, I can treat them as vectors. My vague question that I want to ask is "How similar are these two vectors". I've chosen to measure similarity between the vectors using Pearson's correlation coefficient (corrcoef() in matlab).

However, I'm only able to compute the correlation between $S$ and $T$, not $P$ and $Q$. If I have very good estimates of $P$ and $Q$ I might not care, but the amount of data I have means that my estimates not great (still useful though). Given a noisy estimate of the inputs, my computation of the correlation will be biased towards zero. I've seen this referred to as Spearman's attenuation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correction_for_attenuation).

That wiki page also offers a correction for the attenuation, but in the derivation it assumes that the errors between different bins are independent, which is not the case when estimating a probability distribution. So my question is 1) Is there a known way to correct correlation attenuation in this sort of case? 2) If not, are there related topics/papers that might help?

Comment: The meaning of a correlation between two probability distributions is unclear. Can you further clarify what you are computing and how?

Comment: The Pearson correlation coefficient. If you treat the distributions as vectors, then the correlation coefficient is a measure of similarity between the two distributions with a range of -1 to 1. I hope that makes things clearer.

Comment: Exactly what is your case?  What assumptions *are* you making about these distributions?

Comment: Can you add an example about what  kind of data you have, how the estimates are obtained and how the correlation coefficient is computed?

Comment: I just made a large edit. I hope that clarifies the question.

Comment: Thank you for the additional description.  For most conceivable purposes, Pearson's correlation is an inferior way to compare two discrete distributions.  Could you explain *why* you are comparing them?  That might help your readers identify more appropriate methods.

Comment: Sure. Each distribution represents points on an image that people have selected using one of two methods (P and Q) and I'm trying to see whether they tend to select the same locations using each method. I've binned the image sufficiently coarsely that I'm not worried about accidentally selecting one bin when you mean to select another, or any other neighborhood effects. I'm using Pearson correlation because the literature is full of it and my audience (psychologists) will understand it easily.

Comment: I should also note that the problem I'm running into with Pearson correlation (estimate variability decreasing the measure of similarity) would probably be a problem for another measure of similarity.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if using the ["Gini coefficient"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient) will be useful in your context. From the Wiki "The Gini coefficient measures the inequality among values of a frequency distribution (for example, levels of income)."

Comment: Hmmm... Wouldn't the Gini coefficient be subject to the same problem? That the noise on the estimates $S$ and $T$ would make them seem more dissimilar than they actually are?

Comment: Just thinking out aloud ...I think that any measure will be affected by the noise in your estimates. In your case i wonder if the Gini index ( or its relatives) is a better estimator in comparison to the correlation coefficient as it will at least obviate the need for independence among your binned values. Hope this is useful

Comment: It is useful. I agree that any measure will be affected by noise (and the Gini coefficient may be more useful). Do you know of a way to quantify the noise effect in this case?